# Algunos textos desbordan su espacio en la ventana "Selecciona tu siguiente medalla"

Tags: bug, perfil

Al abrir la ventana `"selecciona tu siguiente medalla"` en el perfil de usuario, hay un par de casos en los que la descripción de la medalla es demasiado larga para el espacio que tiene asignado y se sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso `Google Chrome` con el zoom al 125%. Si lo reduzco al 100% el texto se reordena y en algunos casos se soluciona el problema, en otros no.

Comment: @Mariano No es un problema de traducción, el texto es correcto. Es un problema de diseño gráfico.

Comment: Yo lo veo bien. Convendría que pongas explorador y versión (y ver que el zoom esté en 100% -en 110% desborda)

Comment: Uso Chrome y en efecto con el zoom al 100% se ve bien en algunos casos, no en todos. De todas formas no puedes decirle a los usuarios "¡Hey! Este sitio sólo se ve bien con el zoom al 100%, si eres corto de vista te fastidias". El diseño debe ser responsivo.

Comment: Por supuesto! Era solo una recomendación para que agregues en la descripción.. Se tiene que poder reproducir antes de intentar arreglarlo

Comment: Ah, vale, entiendo. Pregunta ampliada, gracias.